# How to get precision of BigDecimal type data in an @Entity class

Tags: java, bigdecimal

I have an @Entity class in which there is an instance like this

```
@Column(name="some_column_in_table", precision=3, scale=1)
    private BigDecimal someColumnInTable;
```

How can I get precision of that instance?

Comment: Could You explain exactly what do You want?

The annotation states, what is the precision of the column in the DB. You want the instance of BigDecimal precision?

Comment: Yes the annotatio says its precision is 3, but how can I check this with code?

Comment: You can find it in my answer below - using reflection

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/persistence/Column.html
If You just want to programatically get the value set in the annotation, You can do it. The retention for Column is set to RUNTIME, so using Reflection it is possible.

```
Field f = MyClass.class.getDeclaredField("someColumnInTable")) { 
Column column = f.getAnnotation(Column.class);
if (column != null){
   System.out.println(column.precision());
}
```

Here are some other examples how to do it:
[Is it possible to read the value of a annotation in java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4296910/is-it-possible-to-read-the-value-of-a-annotation-in-java)

Comment: MyClass.class.getFields() is returning empty list of fields.

Comment: When I used `MyClass.class.getField("someColumnInTable");` It throws NoSuchFieldException.

Comment: @Varun sorry, it's private, use getDeclaredField instead (edited)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not quite sure if i got your problem correctly, but have you tried

```
 someColumnInTable.precision()
```

as told by the BigDecimal JavaDoc?

Comment: Yes I tried this. This return precision of value stored in the instance of BigDecimal. This does not work.