# How to obtain Class from JPA entity name?

Tags: class, jpa, entity

Is there a way to find out the

```
  java.lang.Class
```

that is the one having

```
@Entity(name = "X")?
```

In other words use the Entity Name to get the classname of the Entity, of course at runtime :)

Comment: Of interest, possibly answering the question entirely if you read through all answers: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4296910/is-it-possible-to-read-the-value-of-a-annotation-in-java .

Comment: @Gimby I don't think that gets us very far, since you'd also need a way to find all potentially matching entity classes on the classpath.

Comment: @M.Justin that comment is almost a decade old.

Comment: @Gimby Both questions are still topical, so the fact that it's an old comment isn't really an issue (except that it's of more benefit to future readers than the original asker of the question).  The fact that it doesn't directly address the question is of relevance to people who are looking for a solution in 2024 and beyond.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

All registered `@Entity`s are available by [`MetaModel#getEntities()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/metamodel/Metamodel.html#getEntities--). It returns a `List<EntityType<?>>` whereby the [`EntityType`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/metamodel/EntityType.html) has a [`getName()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/metamodel/EntityType.html#getName--) method representing the `@Entity(name)` and a [`getJavaType()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/metamodel/Type.html#getJavaType--) representing the associated `@Entity` class. The `MetaModel` instance is in turn available by [`EntityManager#getMetaModel()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/EntityManager.html#getMetamodel--).

In other words, here's the approach in flavor of an utility method:

```
public static Class<?> getEntityClass(EntityManager entityManager, String entityName) {
    for (EntityType<?> entity : entityManager.getMetamodel().getEntities()) {
        if (entityName.equals(entity.getName())) {
            return entity.getJavaType();
        }
    }

    return null;
}
```

Comment: This solution works, however we have thousands of entities and looping through every time is expensive,,,,

Comment: @amitsalyan: If you need to do the mapping multiple times, it's easy to cache mappings in a map with entity names as keys, and Class instances as values

Answer (score 1):

I've raised an issue in the JPA spec to be able to load entity by entity name in 2014:

https://github.com/jakartaee/persistence/issues/85

This was finally implemented seven years later, in 2023.  It is currently part of [Jakarta Persistence 3.2.0-B02](https://github.com/jakartaee/persistence/releases/tag/3.2-DRAFT01-3.2.0-B01-RELEASE), a prerelease version of the next planned release.

Answer (score 0):

The ability to get an entity by name is being added to the upcoming Jakarta Persistence 3.2 by way of the new [`Metamodel.entity(String entityName)`](https://jakartaee.github.io/persistence/latest/api/jakarta.persistence/jakarta/persistence/metamodel/Metamodel.html#entity(java.lang.String)) method.

```java
public static Class<?> getEntityClass(EntityManager entityManager,
                                      String entityName) {
    return entityManager.getMetamodel().entity(entityName).getJavaType();
}
```