# Multiple fields (custom + notnull) validation while using spring validation

Tags: java, spring, bean-validation

I have a `dto` like this

```
@FieldMatch(first = "email", second = "emailConfirm", message = "E-posta adresleri eslesmeli")
public class EmailDTO {


    private String email;


    private String emailConfirm;
```

this is validator

```
public class FieldMatchValidator implements ConstraintValidator<FieldMatch, Object> {


    private String firstFieldName;
    private String secondFieldName;
    private String message;

    @Override
    public void initialize(final FieldMatch constraintAnnotation) {
        firstFieldName = constraintAnnotation.first();
        secondFieldName = constraintAnnotation.second();
        message = constraintAnnotation.message();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isValid(final Object value, final ConstraintValidatorContext context) {
        boolean valid = true;
        try
        {
            final Object firstObj = BeanUtils.getProperty(value, firstFieldName);
            final Object secondObj = BeanUtils.getProperty(value, secondFieldName);

            valid =  firstObj == null && secondObj == null || firstObj != null && firstObj.equals(secondObj);
        }
        catch (final Exception ignore)
        {
            // ignore
        }

        if (!valid){
            context.buildConstraintViolationWithTemplate(message)
                    .addPropertyNode(firstFieldName)
                    .addConstraintViolation()
                    .disableDefaultConstraintViolation();
        }

        return valid;
    }
}
```

this is interface

```
arget({TYPE, ANNOTATION_TYPE})
@Retention(RUNTIME)
@Constraint(validatedBy = FieldMatchValidator.class)
@Documented
public @interface FieldMatch {


    String message() default "The fields must match";
    Class<?>[] groups() default {};
    Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default {};
    String first();
    String second();

    @Target({TYPE, ANNOTATION_TYPE})
    @Retention(RUNTIME)
    @Documented
    @interface List
    {
        FieldMatch[] value();
    }
}
```

but i also want to change the class to this

```
@FieldMatch(first = "email", second = "emailConfirm", message = "E-posta adresleri eslesmeli")
public class EmailDTO {



     @Max(value = 150, message = "E-posta karakter sayisi fazla!")
        @Email(message = "Email should be valid")
        @NotNull(message = "Name cannot be null")
        @NotEmpty(message = "Name cannot be null")
        private String email;

        @Max(value = 150, message = "E-posta karakter sayisi fazla!")
        @Email(message = "Email should be valid")
        @NotNull(message = "Name cannot be null")
        @NotEmpty(message = "Name cannot be null")
        private String emailConfirm;
```

Should I use another generic constraint or a lot of annotations like shown above? I also have other entities like `password`, etc and those entities will also have same validations.

Some fields can be `nullable`, so not every field has to be checked by null constraint. I want to do a very generic validation. I will send to front end (`thymeleaf`), so I need to see which constraint is  violated.

Email has `@email` annotation that wont be in the password validation. Others are common. like

```
notnull, notempty, matching, notblank
```

I was not able to find good examples. I found below posts on the topic, but I could not find an example of custom + for example `@email` validation together.

- [spring-custom-annotation-validation-with-multiple-field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40353638/spring-custom-annotation-validation-with-multiple-field)
- [how-can-i-validate-two-or-more-fields-in-combination](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2781771/how-can-i-validate-two-or-more-fields-in-combination)
- [spring-mvc-custom-validator](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-mvc-custom-validator) post shows validation for different fields.