# Using Java annotations

Tags: java

If I have an annotation in Java, for example "LayoutID" which is defined :

```
@interface LayoutID {
   int value();
}
```

And used like the following :

```
@LayoutID(R.id.text) private EditText mEditText;
```

How is it possible to access the attribute value of the annotation for that specific variable?

Comment: Reflection is the way to go

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to read the value of a annotation in java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4296910/is-it-possible-to-read-the-value-of-a-annotation-in-java)