# Get property value of annotation (used on a class, not method)

Tags: java, annotations, spring-annotations, hibernate-annotations, java-annotations

Scenario is something like below...

```
@Component
@Migration(description="Test Description", serial="")
public class TestUpdate1 {

}
```

I need to get the value of **description**
i.e. **"Test Description"**

How can I do that

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to read the value of a annotation in java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4296910/is-it-possible-to-read-the-value-of-a-annotation-in-java)

Answer (score 0):

You can possibly get the value like this way

```
JsonElement jsonElement = methods[i].getAnnotation(JsonElement.class);

int type = jsonElement.type();
```

Comment: I need to get the value of a annotation property(description) where the annotation applied on a class(see the example), not on a method