# Receive annotation value from annotated field

Tags: java, spring, reflection, annotations, runtime

Is it possible to receive annotation value inside a field, that was annotated?
Imagine that I have this interface:

```
@Target(ElementType.FIELD)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface MyAnnotation {
    String value();
}
```

And I have such implementation:

```
class SomeClass {
    @MyAnnotation("Annotation")
    private MyClass myClass;
}
```

What I want to understand is: is it possible to receive value of MyAnnotation inside MyClass? I want to implement a method inside class MyClass, which will return a value of assigned annotation. So, that `myClass.getAssignedAnnotationValue()` will return "Annotation".
If it is not possible, please inform me.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to read the value of a annotation in java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4296910/is-it-possible-to-read-the-value-of-a-annotation-in-java)

Comment: No, it is not
I am asking, is it possible to know annotation value inside annotated field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> is it possible to know annotation value inside annotated field

It's not possible.

You may have 2 different classes

```
class SomeClass {
    @MyAnnotation("Annotation")
    private MyClass myClass;
    public SomeClass(MyClass myClass) {
        this.myClass=myClass;
    }
}
```

and

```
class SomeClassNo Annotation {
    private MyClass myClass;
    public SomeClassNo(MyClass myClass) {
        this.myClass=myClass;
    }
}
```

Then you create an instance of MyClass

MyClass instance = new MyClass();

then 2 classes instances
`new SomeClass(instance)` and `new SomeClassNo(instance)` both have reference to the same `instance`. So the instance does not know whether the reference field  annotated or not.

The only case when it is possible is to pass somehow the container reference to `MyClass`.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation

Comment: You don’t even need a second class to show the ambiguity. A `MyClass` instance may live an arbitrary long time before it gets assigned to the annotated `SomeClass.myClass` field. Or it may be referenced by the annotated field for some time, before it gets reassigned, so the object is not referenced by the annotated field anymore. Being referenced is not a property of the object…

Answer (score 0):

There is no straight forward way of implementing what you are asking.

**WorkAround:**

Limitations:

1. This workaround doesn't enforce any kind of compile time check and it is completely your responsibility to handle it.
2. This only works if MyClass is going to be a spring bean.

---

```
class MyClass {
    public String annotatedValue;
}
```

You can write a Spring BeanPostProcessor the following way.

```
public class SampleBeanPostProcessor implements BeanPostProcessor {

    @Override
    public Object postProcessBeforeInitialization(Object bean, String beanName)
        throws BeansException {

        return bean;
    }

    @Override
    public Object postProcessAfterInitialization(Object bean, String beanName)
        throws BeansException {

        Field[] fields = bean.getClass().getDeclaredFields();
        for (Field field : fields) {
            if (field instanceof MyClass && field.isAnnotationPresent(MyAnnotation.class)) {
                String value = field.getDeclaredAnnotation(MyAnnotation.class).value();
                ((MyClass) field).annotatedValue = value;
                return bean;
            }
        }
        return bean;
    }
}
```

The above BeanPostProcessor will be called for every bean during the app start up. It will check all the fields of a given bean to see if the field is of type `MyClass`. If it is, it will extract the value from the annotation and set it in the `annotatedValue` field.

The problem with this approach is that you can use MyAnnotation on any property in any class. **You cannot enforce the annotation to be used only on MyClass.**