# Is there any way to get the xpath of element stored following page object model from a separate file?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath

Suppose I have stored WebElment in **LoginPage.java** class as shown below.

```
@FindBy(xpath="//input[@name='user_name']") WebElement username;
```

Now from my test file say **VerifyLogin.java** I want to access xpath of username which is stored in above **LoginPage.java** file something like this

```
LoginPage loginPage = PageFactory.initElements(driver, LoginPage.class);
loginPage.username;//then it should return the xpath //input[@name='user_name']
```

I know the above approach is wrong, but is there any way to get only the xpath that was stored in LoginPage file that I can use in VerifyLogin file?

Comment: I'm curious why you need the xpath itself, but to answer the question I would probably just define a String variable in LoginPage that contains the xPath and use that.

Comment: Yes I am aware if xpath is stored as String variable then I can achieve it, then in this case I will miss the page object model feature as I am storing all web element using @FindBy and creating method based on pages. So I don't want change it.

Comment: You can find helpful information [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4296910/is-it-possible-to-read-the-value-of-a-annotation-in-java)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need it outside of the page object then your design is not that good .

Anyhow if you really want it the following should do the job

```
@FindBy(xpath="//input[@name='user_name']") 
public WebElement username;
```

`new YourPageObject().username;`

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why you need to see the xpath after it's done its job but you can do something like this:

```
public final String xUserName = "//input[@name='user_name']";
@FindBy(xpath = xUserName)
public WebElement username;
```

The `final` attribute is required.

This way you store the path as a string, and use the string in your POM, but it is still readable as a string. I start the String variable with `x` so I know that the String is in xpath format. Start with `c` for CSS Selector notation.

I've done similar for a couple reasons:

1. The actual xpath is gigantic so I break it into smaller, reusable String chunks. But for that I mark the String as private.
2. I need the string to pass to other Selenium methods such as a pause class I created.

But to answer the direct question, **no**, you can't get the xpath from a POM variable because that information is not stored. The variable is a WebElement and doesn't care by what method you assigned it. It's like asking how a String was created.

Answer (score 0):

you can use this small trick , I used it and it worked for me.

toString method lets you print webelement which has its xpath in it
then using substring method get ur xpath

// method to fetch xpath from PageFacotry webElement

```
public String getXpathFromWebelement(WebElement e) {   
        String xpath = e.toString();
        xpath = xpath.substring(xpath.indexOf("/"), xpath.lastIndexOf("]"));
        return xpath;
    }
```