# How to get the @Qualifier member value?

Tags: java, dependency-injection, cdi, inject, weld

I have an @InterceptorBinding with member value like this:

```
@Target({ElementType.METHOD, ElementType.TYPE})
@InterceptorBinding
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface Transactional {
    boolean value() default true;
}
```

and an @Interceptor :

```
@Interceptor
@Transactional
public class TransactionInterceptor {

    @Inject
    private EntityManager em;

    @AroundInvoke
    public Object runInTransaction(InvocationContext invocationContext) throws Exception {

    // here i want get the @Transactional's member value
```

I'm using it like this:

```
@Transactional(true)
    public String insertDatatypes(String s1) {

        //some logic
        ...
```

My question is :

Is it possible to get the value **true** used in @Transactional(**true**) in my TransactionInterceptor class ?

Thanks for your help

Comment: I don't have an example at hand nor time to search SO for a duplicate, but yes afaik you can via reflection

Comment: thanks for the answer, i'll search for some reflection example and let you know if i could resolve it, (i'm new to cdi)

Comment: There is no duplicate of this in stackoverflow?

Answer (score 0):

I could get the member value like this

```
boolean trans = invocationContext.getMethod().getAnnotation(Transactional.class).value();
```

Comment: There is no duplicate of this in stackoverflow?

Comment: i can't found a duplication !

Comment: searching for 'How to read the value of an anotation' in stackoverflow resulted in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4296910/is-it-possible-to-read-the-value-of-a-annotation-in-java