# How to get @JsonProperty 's value using java and jackson api?

Tags: java, jackson, jackson-databind

In one of the cases in my project , I encountered a case where I need to fetch JSONPropoerty name to build another json object.

I have a pojo class:

```
 public class Records {
    @JsonProperty("NEWVALUE")
    private String new;
}
```

now in another class I need to create JSON Object using the json property names associated with my Record pojo class's @JsonProperty names.

I want something like

```
Record rec=new Record();
JsonNode tmpNode=new JsonNode();
String key= <somehow get value from rec object i.e. "NEWVALUE">
((ObjectNode) tmpNode).put(key, "abc"));
```

Is there any way to get the json property names associated with java field names.

Comment: something like this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4296910/is-it-possible-to-read-the-value-of-a-annotation-in-java

Answer (score 2):

Even so, `Jackson`, has classes like `com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.introspect.JacksonAnnotationIntrospector`, `com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.introspect.AnnotatedField`, etc... I would recommend to not use if it is really not required. They have really sophisticated `API` and works only for objects from `com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.introspect` which you need to create somehow.

The easiest solution is to create `public static final` field and use in another class:

```
class Records {

    public static final String NEW_VALUE = "NEWVALUE";

    @JsonProperty(NEW_VALUE)
    private String value;
}
```

And you can use it as below:

```
((ObjectNode) tmpNode).put(Records.NEW_VALUE, "abc"));
```

Or, just use `Reflection` to read an annotation from given field.

See also:

- [What is reflection and why is it useful?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37628/what-is-reflection-and-why-is-it-useful)

Comment: Yes, that is good workaround using public static final field.

Comment: Good advice on setting values for the name instead of using reflection.