# Using Converters to truncate fields based on Size annotation

Tags: java, jpa

I have an entity where I set the `max` for every String field like the following:

```
@Column(name = "abc")
@Size(max = 10)
private String abc;

@Column(name = "xyz")
@Size(max = 50)
private String xyz;
```

I want to write a Converter to truncate that field if exceeds max size. Something like this:

```
import javax.persistence.AttributeConverter;
import javax.persistence.Convert;

@Convert
public class TruncatedStringConverter implements AttributeConverter<String, String> {
  private static final int LIMIT = 999;

  @Override
  public String convertToDatabaseColumn(String attribute) {
    if (attribute == null) {
      return null;
    } else if (attribute.length() > LIMIT) {
      return attribute.substring(0, LIMIT);
    } else {
      return attribute;
    }
  }

  @Override
  public String convertToEntityAttribute(String dbData) {
    return dbData;
  }
}
```

But the thing is that I can't use `LIMIT` since I need to look to the Size annotation. Is there any way to access the field name from the converter?

This way I could use reflection to read the max size.

Thank you!

Comment: Maybe this one helps you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4296910/is-it-possible-to-read-the-value-of-a-annotation-in-java

Comment: thanks @RalfRenz! I can read field name from field.getName() using getDeclaredFields but I'm wondering if there's a way to access inside the converter. I only know the value inside the converter but I am not sure from which variable it belongs :)

Comment: There is a much easier solution to this:  Move the `@Column` and `@Size` annotations to the get-method of each property.  For example, `@Size(max = LIMIT) public String getXyz() { return xyz; }`.  Then the corresponding set-method can take care of truncation.

Comment: That's also a possibility! Or maybe I will just write one method to go over the entire entity object after it gets filled out/ Thanks @VGR!